# Stable Marriage Problem - code returning no partners/choices for anyone

Tags: java, linked-list

I think the problem lies with the int w1 variable. I can't directly reference that with the lists, so I can't state if that specific woman prefers that man (m) over the current man (m1).

I have tried many different ways of solving this problem but all of them result in the same output of no matches being made and everyone staying single and I can't figure out where I have gone wrong.

```
    public static void makeMatches(List<Person> list1, List<Person> list2) {
        // set each person to be free
        for (Person m : list1) {
            m.erasePartner();
        }

        for (Person w: list2) {
            w.erasePartner();
        }


        for (Person m : list1) {
            for (Person w : list2) {
                // find man with nonempty preference list that is free      
                while (m.hasChoices() && !m.hasPartner()) {
                    // first woman on man's list
                    int w1 = m.getFirstChoice();

                    for (Person m1 : list1) {
                        // if chosen woman is free, set her to be man's partner
                        if (!w.hasPartner()) {m.setPartner(w1);

                        // if chosen woman has partner, set her to be free and engage her and man
                        } else if (w.hasPartner()) {
                            if (w.getPartnerRank() < w.getChoices().indexOf(m)) {
                            w.erasePartner();
                            m.setPartner(w1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
import java.util.*;

public class Person {
    public static final int NOBODY = -1;

    private String name;
    private List<Integer> preferences;
    private List<Integer> oldPreferences;
    private int partner;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        preferences = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        oldPreferences = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        erasePartner();
    }

    public void erasePartner() {
        partner = NOBODY;
    }

    public boolean hasPartner() {
        return partner != NOBODY;
    }

    public int getPartner() {
        return partner;
    }

    public void setPartner(int partner) {
        this.partner = partner;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean hasChoices() {
        return !preferences.isEmpty();
    }

    public int getFirstChoice() {
        return preferences.get(0);
    }

    public void addChoice(int person) {
        preferences.add(person);
        oldPreferences.add(person);
    }

    public List<Integer> getChoices() {
        return preferences;
    }

    public int getPartnerRank() {
        return oldPreferences.indexOf(partner) + 1;
    }
}
```

test file:
Man 0: 3 0 1 2
Man 1: 1 2 0 3
Man 2: 1 3 2 0
Man 3: 2 0 3 1
END
Woman 0: 3 0 2 1
Woman 1: 0 2 1 3
Woman 2: 0 1 2 3
Woman 3: 3 0 2 1
END

output:
Matches for men

### Name           Choice  Partner

Man 0             --    nobody
Man 1             --    nobody
Man 2             --    nobody
Man 3             --    nobody
Mean choice = NaN

Matches for women

### Name           Choice  Partner

Woman 0          --    nobody
Woman 1          --    nobody
Woman 2          --    nobody
Woman 3          --    nobody
Mean choice = NaN
The results should pair each man with a woman, using the Gale-Shapley algorithm.

Comment: how does it "go wrong"?

Comment: Precisely, what makes you think you have gone wrong? Did you try running this? Are you getting any errors? Is there any way that we could see them? Also, can you show us the class `Person`?

Comment: my output: 
Matches for men
Name           Choice  Partner
--------------------------------------
Man 0             --    nobody
Man 1             --    nobody
Man 2             --    nobody
Man 3             --    nobody
Mean choice = NaN

Matches for women
Name           Choice  Partner
--------------------------------------
Woman 0          --    nobody
Woman 1          --    nobody
Woman 2          --    nobody
Woman 3          --    nobody
Mean choice = NaN

Comment: @mike1 could we see some test cases? like an input and then an expected vs actual output?

Comment: I added the input as well as the output that I am getting.

Comment: @mike1 also how are you getting the output currently? are you just looping through the list of men, getting their partners? then looping through the list of women, getting their partners?

Comment: @ChrisGong I am following the Gale-Shapley algorithm but I feel like it isn't doing what it is supposed to. It should go through the men first and pair them with the women they prefer, if the woman first on their list is already married, it should look at the woman's preferences and check if the man that she is already married to is higher on her ranking list than the new man and either stay married to the current man, or break it off for the man higher on her preferences. The full list of people that will be graded on contains 40 men and 35 women, so there will be some men with no partners.

Comment: I think you don't need `for (Person m1 : list1) `,  at least you are not using `m1` inside the loop, right?

Comment: @mikel1 does my answer address your question?

Comment: @ChrisGong it definitely helps with a lot of the structure problems, but the one thing that still isn't working is defining the m1 variable. I cant refer to the preferences because they are private, and I can't create the new method stillNotEngaged because it no longer even gives any output at all when I add that into the code. It just asks what the file name is, I type it in and nothing happens. I'm just struggling with what to create m1 as because it needs to be an integer, but I can't figure out how to define it.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues here. First off, I'm not sure why you have this double for loop structure in `makeMatches`. The condition of Gale-Shapley is to iterate through the list of men as long as there exists at least one man who is still not engaged, but still has someone to propose to that he has not already proposed to. So I would remove the double for loop and keep the while loop, but instead change the condition inside to call a method, perhaps call it `stillNotEngaged` that returns the index of someone in the list of males who is not engaged and still has choices, and -1 or `NOBODY` if they are all engaged or don't have any choices left.

```
public static void makeMatches(List<Person> list1, List<Person> list2) {
    // code from before that set each partner free
    int m1 = stillNotEngaged(list1, list2);
    while (m1 != -1) { // at least one not engaged or has choices
        // to be filled in later in this answer...
        m1 = stillNotEngaged(list1, list2);
    }
}

public static int stillNotEngaged(List<Person> men, List<Person> women) {
    for (int i = 0; i < men.size(); i++) {
        if (!men.get(i).hasPartner() && men.get(i).hasChoices()) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return NOBODY;
}
```

Then, make sure to set the partner of **BOTH** the man and woman. Before you were only setting the partner of just the man. And if a divorce does occur, don't just clear the woman's partner, clear **BOTH** the man and woman's partners. Or to make it easier, in the case of a divorce, just clear the old husband's partner, and set the new husband and wife's partners. Lastly, I'm not really sure why you're using `oldPreferences` nor why you're adding 1 to the rank in the `getPartnerRank` method, why not just use the index of the partner in `preferences` like so,

```
public int getPartnerRank() {
    return preferences.indexOf(partner);
}
```

Another thing to also keep in mind is that when a man proposes, you should remove that woman from the man's preferences otherwise the loop will be infinite. Gary-Shapley only has the men propose to each woman at most once, so perhaps consider making a method called `removeChoice` like so,

```
public void removeChoice(int w) {
    preferences.remove(preferences.indexOf(w));
}
```

All in all, if you implement the new changes I just mentioned, your `makeMatches` method should now look like this,

```
 public static void makeMatches(List<Person> list1, List<Person> list2) {
    // set each person to be free
    for (Person m : list1) {
        m.erasePartner();
    }

    for (Person w: list2) {
        w.erasePartner();
    }

    int m1 = stillNotEngaged(list1, list2);
    while (m1 != -1) { // at least one not engaged and has choices
        int w1 = m.getFirstChoice();
        Person m = list1.get(m1);
        Person w = list2.get(w1);
        if (!w.hasPartner()) {
            m.setPartner(w1);
            w.setPartner(m1);
        }
        // if chosen woman has partner, set her to be free and engage her and man
        else if (w.hasPartner()) {
            // assuming preferences are in descending order, so index 0 is the first priority choice
            if (w.getPartnerRank() > w.getChoices().indexOf(m1)) {
                list1.get(w.getPartner()).erasePartner();
                w.setPartner(m1);
                m.setPartner(w1);
            }
        }
        m.removeChoice(w1);
        m1 = stillNotEngaged(list1, list2);
    }
}
```